# pressure from euler's equation of inviscid flow

Tags: multivariable-calculus, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

For an inviscid fluid with constant density, how do you derive an expression for pressure from the equation

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \left(u\cdot\nabla\right)u = -\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla P + f. $$

Comment: What do you mean?